# Im getting an error when i debug on this function C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I get this error IndexOutOfRangeException Unhandled at the line that comment says "why must you break here" At Click of login Button it runs two functions a encryption algorithm to get hash to compare to hash that was Queried From The database.
Then It makes a comparison is the hash generated from Plain text match the one in Database if matches the run second query of selecting the Access Level from the database where Username equals the inputted Username if access Level is at a certain level then grant certain Permissions.

```
 private void btn_ProLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {// at click of login button you take the plaintext password and convert it to     sha1 Base 64 encoded
        string s = txt_ProgramPass.Text.ToString();
        byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);
        SHA1 algorithm = SHA1.Create();
        byte[] hash = algorithm.ComputeHash(data);
        string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
        MessageBox.Show(base64);
        //txtUaHash.Text = base64;
        string sConn;
        string sQuery;

        string hashfromDB = "hash2";
        sConn = "datasource = " + Properties.Settings.Default.Hostname + "; username = " + Properties.Settings.Default.ServerLogin + ";password = " + Properties.Settings.Default.ServerPassword + "; port = " + Properties.Settings.Default.ServerPort + "; database = " + Properties.Settings.Default.ServerDB;
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(sConn);
        MySqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
        sQuery = "Select UPassword FROM  accounts  WHERE Username = '"+txt_ProgramLogin.Text+"'";
        // also at login you query the Database to pull the hashed password from UPassword column where the Username text = the Username

        try
        {

            command.CommandText = sQuery;
            MessageBox.Show(sQuery); //Debug Method
            conn.Open();
            MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();//Column NUmber 5 in databse is the UPassword Field and it is a varchar that converts to string
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    string password;
                    if (reader.IsDBNull(5) == false) //why Must you Break Here
                    {
                        password = reader.GetString(5);
                        if (password != null) hashfromDB = password.ToString();// Take password from Database and Insert into Variable hashfromDB
                    }
                }
            }


        }
        catch(MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        if (base64 == "hash2")// Take Previosly encode Plaintext Password and COmpare to Has pulled from Database
            //(base64 == hashfromDB) or (hashfromDB == base64) ("hash2" == base64)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(hashfromDB); //Debug Method
            try
            {
                string sQuery2;//then if they Match query Database again where username is equal to username textbox.text
                sQuery2 = "Select ACCESSLEVEL From accounts Where Username ='" + txt_ProgramLogin.Text + "'"; //select access level from database where the username matches
                command.CommandText = sQuery2;
                MessageBox.Show(sQuery2); //Debug Method
                conn.Open();
                MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        int AccessLvL;
                        if (reader.IsDBNull(6) == false)//then compare access level to access level integer and then grant Permissions based off the value from database
                        {//enable disable buttons and functions based on access level 
                            AccessLvL = reader.GetInt32(6);
                            if (AccessLvL == 1)
                            {
                                string roAccess;
                                roAccess = "Sorry, "+ txt_ProgramLogin.Text +"You Can Login But You Have No Access";
                                MessageBox.Show(roAccess, "No Access", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

                            }
                            if (AccessLvL == 2)
                            {
                                string KeyholderAccess;
                                KeyholderAccess = "KeyHolder Username Found. " + txt_ProgramLogin.Text + "You Have Keyholder access to Program";
                                MessageBox.Show(KeyholderAccess, "Keyholder Access", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

                            }
                            if (AccessLvL == 3)
                            {
                                string sFtWare;
                                sFtWare = "Software Administrator Username Found. " + txt_ProgramLogin.Text + "You Have Access to The Software and Software Keys";
                                MessageBox.Show(sFtWare, "Software Access", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                            }
                            if (AccessLvL == 4)
                            {
                                string ProgramAdministrator;
                                ProgramAdministrator = "Administrative Username Found. " + txt_ProgramLogin.Text +  "You have Full Access to Program.";
                                MessageBox.Show(ProgramAdministrator, "Administrative Access", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                                frmUserMenu umenu = new frmUserMenu();
                                umenu.Show();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }


            }
            catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }


        }
        else
        {
            string sMsg;
            sMsg = "I'm Sorry Your Username Password is Wrong Speak To Your Program Administrator.";
            MessageBox.Show(sMsg);
            txt_ProgramLogin.Clear();
            txt_ProgramPass.Clear();
        }
    }
```

Any Ideas Please read the comments in code sample thanks.

Comment: Its a zero based index, meaning column number 5 needs `reader.IsDBNull(4)`

Comment: This is column 6 there is total of 7 columns

Comment: well then, better do as the answers suggest use `GetOrdinal`

Comment: Im confused what do you mean column 6 (5) is where the password value is that i want it to compare to.

Comment: well, i was wrong, since you are not selecting all columns there is only 1 column, meaning `reader.IsDBNull(0)` as elrich00 answer

Comment: So since i didnt write query as select * from accounts it doesnt understand what i want it to do.

Comment: yes exactly, you are not getting columns from the table, you are getting it from the command you used

Comment: *facepalm i feel noobish lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are only asking to return the UPassword field in your SELECT query. Therefore, the UPassword value is going to be in index 0, not index 5

Answer (score 2):

You are only returning one column (UPassword) in your result set. Then you are passing the ordinal 5 which means try to get the value of the 6th column in the result set (which doesn't exist).

what you can do is get the column ordinal by name like so:

```
   int uPasswordIndex = reader.GetOrdinal("UPassword");
```

Then in your code use the index in the isDbNull check:

```
    string password;
    if (reader.IsDBNull(uPasswordIndex) == false) //why Must you Break Here
    {
        password = reader.GetString(uPasswordIndex);
        if (password != null) hashfromDB = password.ToString();// Take password from Database and Insert into Variable hashfromDB
    }
```